# With function replace rule does not work in

Tags: replacement, scoping

If I define an expression , and evaluate it in **With** function, replace rule does not work.

```
sumT = TA + TE;
With[
 {TA = 0.1, TE = 0.2},
 {TA + TE, sumT}
 ]
```

output

```
{0.3, TA + TE}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
sumT = TA + TE;
With[
 {TA = 0.1, TE = 0.2},
  Evaluate@{TA + TE, sumT}
 ]
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation  ?

Comment: `With` has the attribute `HoldAll`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `With` with `Block`:

```
sumT = TA + TE;

Block[{TA = 0.1, TE = 0.2}, {TA + TE, sumT}]
```

{0.3, 0.3}

```
Block[{TA = 0.1, TE = 0.5}, {TA + TE, sumT}]
```

{0.6, 0.6}

From its `Documentation` details:

"`Block` allows you to set up an environment in which the values of variables can **temporarily** be changed."

Comment: In fact, I have a bit complex function , I combine With in Block. Because I first get  a lot of formulas , then I verify them by passing real number.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to

> Could you give some explanation ?

Just follow the evaluation process

1. `With[ {TA = 0.1, TE = 0.2}, {TA + TE, sumT} ]`
2. `{0.1 + 0.2, sumT}`
3. `{0.3,sumT}`
4. `{0.3, TA + TE}`

The way `With` works is that it holds everything unevaluated, performs the substitutions "formally", and then "goes away" and lets the resulting expression continue evaluating. You can think of the `TA` and `TE` inside of the `With` as local variables if you want. Once the `With` has been handled (step 2), we're now back at the main scope, and `sumT` will be replaced according to its `OwnValues`.